# What is the difference between return in these two functions?

Tags: javascript, return

In this function i didn't need return:-

```
function sayHello() {
   var test = "test return"
   alert(test);
 }

 sayHello();
```

But in this i needed it:-

```
function randomNumber(range) {
  return Math.round( Math.random() * range );
}
alert(randomNumber(2));
```

Why that ?

Comment: Your first function doesn't need a return because you don't need a value from it, whereas randonNumber is sending you something that you need to use.

Comment: thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

In you first example you are calling alert directly in the function call, so nothing has to be retured.

In the second example you are alerting the value returned from function randomNumber